# RDS and SharePoint 2013 in same server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

You can install SharePoint 2013 single-server in an existing RDS server?

I did an analysis and was in doubt as to IIS and other web services that both applications use.

Comment: what is RDS stands for?

Comment: remote desktop services Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think their should not be an issue rather you will get the benifit of integration of RDS with SharePoint. Below blog is for SharePoint 2010 but still good for 2013.

[Integrating Remote Desktop Services with SharePoint Server 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2012/03/30/integrating-remote-desktop-services-with-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)